# How to use data binding in select parameter of sqlDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a sqlDataSource in which I use select parameter as below :

```
<asp:sqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID"     
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnection %>" RunAt="server">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="<%#userid%>" />
  </SelectParameters>    
</asp:sqlDataSource>
```

In my backend code, I have assigned a value to userId and also written this.DataBind();

The data-binding doesn't work. Does anyone know a solution to this ?

Comment: A good way for us to be able to help you find the problem is that if you include the C# code and the Gridview code you are using

Comment: Like @CarstenLøvboAndersen said, include the c# code. Probably you parameter is EmpID is not binding

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to create this and you couldn't this into a SQL stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**One approach is to just set the value with the userid variable in the code behind Page_Load event or after you bind your variable.**

```
 //set SqlDataSource parameters value with empID as your variable
EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("@EmpID", userID);
```

Asp:

```
 <asp:sqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID"
          RunAt="server"> 
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
      </SelectParameters>
        </asp:sqlDataSource>
```

**Another option is to set the value from code in the selecting event which occurs before a data retrieval.**

**[SqlDataSource.Selecting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

**Here is a link to a more complete example** [Full Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:sqlDataSource ID="EmployeeDetailsSqlDataSource" 
          SelectCommand="SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID"
          RunAt="server" OnSelecting=OnSelectingHandler">
 <SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
 </SelectParameters>
 </asp:sqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
Public void OnSelectingHandler(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{

e.Command.Parameters[0].Value=userID;

}
```